# Saving an email consent doc in researchkit (swift 3.1)

Tags: swift, pdf, researchkit

i would like to be able to save and email a pdf of a consent form from research kit.  Currently, I have the following code to generate the pdf

```
let signatureResult : ORKConsentSignatureResult = taskViewController.result.stepResult(forStepIdentifier: "ConsentReviewStep")?.firstResult as! ORKConsentSignatureResult

let consentDocument = ConsentDocument.copy() as! ORKConsentDocument
signatureResult.apply(to: consentDocument)

consentDocument.makePDF { (data, error) -> Void in

    var documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
    documentsPath.append("consent.pef")
    var documentsURL = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: documentsPath)

    try? data?.write(to: documentsURL, options: [.atomic])
}
```

This first fails with error Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSObjectNotAvailableException', reason: 'Signature title is missing'

Not sure where to go from here to get this part working, before moving on to the mailing function.

Answer (score 0):

For PDF generation, ResearchKit requires that you have a non-nil `title` property in the `ORKConsentSignature` object with which you initialize your `ORKConsentReviewStep`.